# Как сверстать подобное расписание уроков в Андроид?

Tags: android, вёрстка

[image: как можно вывести расписание в таком виде в андроид]

Разбиение по цветам должно быть динамическим.

Comment: есть такой виджет `TableLayoout` специально для таких случаев. Если цвета динамические, то нужно будет в коде менять бэкграунд элементам таблицы.

Comment: @pavlofff да видела этот виджет. Но у него внутри элементы фиксированной высоты.

Comment: Вертикальные LinearLayout как столбцы в горизонтальном. Каждому элементу в столбце выставить вес в виде длины  в часах (1.0, 1.5, 2.0 и тп). Должно получиться.

Comment: @cherry можно, так же, использовать [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html)